# dyld: Library not loaded: Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk

Tags: macos, shell, libreadline

It shows error message as follow when I open the terminal:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Ask this on "SuperUser". Thank you.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

update it with:

"brew upgrade gawk"

This should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been fixed by your way.

Comment: This was the only fix that worked for a similar problem I had where `awk` referenced mpfr4

Comment: I try it and fixed my problem.